# How to control the size of Temporary ASP.NET Files?

Tags: asp.net

In case of a Thin Client Setup for the development setup, the folder becomes very bulk with just 3 developers working at the same time.

Is there any work around that can be done to avoid this?

Comment: What do you mean by "Thin Client Setup for the development setup" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the location of the temporary files folder on a per developer/application basis so that they can delete their own temp files.

See: http://syedgakbar.wordpress.com/2007/11/10/changing-aspnet-temporary-files-folder/